# Having a square root issue in python

Tags: python, sqrt

```
import math 

from scipy.integrate import quad 
def f(p):
    return (math.sqrt(q_values * u_values)**2)

i = quad (f,0,2500)
print (i)
```

This is the error I get:
only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `math.sqrt()` is not vectorized. It expects a scalar. Perhaps you want `np.sqrt()`.

Comment: You should use numpy for this

Comment: what are q_values and u_values?

Answer (score 0):

The Error message "Only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" appears, when a function is expecting a number, like a float, but receives a list with more than one entry.

math.sqrt() expects a float but q_values and u_values are numpy-arrays.

I don't exactly get, what you are trying to do here, because q_values and u_values are not specified in your code, but you defined a function f(x) but you are not working with x but instead two unspecified variables. I would suggest you either edit your question or post it again.

Also here is the docs for that specific function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html